# Format the output of process.argv

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to learn NodeJS, and I've been working with NodeJS built-in functions lately, `process.argv` specifically

Using my code below, I want to print out `Welcome, John Smith`

```
process.argv.forEach((name) => {
    console.log('Welcome, '+`${name}`+'!',);
  });
```

But the output is:

```
Welcome, /usr/local/bin/node!
Welcome, /Users/johnsmith/Desktop/Webbut/NodeJS/5/index.js!
Welcome, Jon!
johnsmith:5 johnsmith$
```

What causes this output when I only want one line to be printed?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.argv.forEach` contains more than what you just passed, see https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

> The process.argv property returns an array containing the command line
>   arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched. The first
>   element will be process.execPath. See process.argv0 if access to the
>   original value of argv[0] is needed. The second element will be the
>   path to the JavaScript file being executed. The remaining elements
>   will be any additional command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` or `argument vector` is an array that contains parts of the command that ran the program. And since you are using `forEach`, it is iterating over the `argv` array and prefixing each element with `Welcome ,`

`argv[0]` is `/usr/local/bin/node` as that's the actual program running your javascript fule

`argv[1]` is `<path to your file>/index.js` as that is the argument passed to node.js as the file to be run by node

`argv[2]` is `Jon` as that is what you are passing as an argument to your script